# Bubble sort class in Java

Tags: java, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel

I have written this class which sorts the array using bubble sort. Please let me know how can I improve it. (I don't like recurrent code in if/else statement)

```
public class BubbleSort {

public static void numbers(int[] array){
    numbers(array, '<');
}

public static void numbers(int[] array, char direction){
    if(direction == '<'){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++){

                if(array[j] < array[j + 1]){
                    int tmp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++){

                if(array[j] > array[j + 1]){
                    int tmp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void letters(char[] array){
    letters(array, '<');
}

public static void letters(char[] array, char direction){
    if(direction == '<'){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++){

                if(array[j] < array[j + 1]){
                    char tmp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++){

                if(array[j] > array[j + 1]){
                    char tmp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bubble Sort has an inefficient worst case.  In general, you could speed things up by switching from this \$O(n^2)\$ sort to one of the \$O(n \log n)\$ sorts, e.g. Quicksort.  Simplest would be to just use `Arrays.sort` but perhaps this is a programming exercise (tagging as [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) would let reviewers know that).

> ```
>         for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
>             for(int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++){
>
>                 if(array[j] < array[j + 1]){
>                     int tmp = array[j];
>                     array[j] = array[j+1];
>                     array[j+1] = tmp;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
> ```

The one thing that Bubble Sort can do well is handle sorted input efficiently in \$O(n)\$ time.  But you don't do that.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            boolean bubbled = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[j + 1]){
                    int tmp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = tmp;
                    bubbled = true;
                }
            }

            if (!bubbled) {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Now it will return after a single pass if the input is sorted.  If the input is almost sorted, it may return on the second or third pass.

You can save a calculation an outer loop iteration if you're really trying to optimize.

```
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            boolean bubbled = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[j + 1]){
                    int tmp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = tmp;
                    bubbled = true;
                }
            }

            if (!bubbled) {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Now you don't have to calculate `array.length - 1 - i` on every outer iteration.

Note that a naive compiler might actually calculate that on each inner iteration in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the outer condition and put it into the inner loop. This will cause it to be calculated O(n^2) times instead of once, but you'll have one copy of your main code:
(**edited!** inner condition fixed)

```
    public static void numbers(int[] array, char direction){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++){

                if(direction == '<' && array[j] < array[j + 1]
                   ||
                   direction == '>' && array[j] > array[j + 1]){
                        int tmp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[j+1];
                        array[j+1] = tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This if condition isn't working because `((true &&  false) || true)`(this condition is always true) and I don't think is good choice make code cleaner for slower algorithm.

Comment: @GRO Of course, you are right! I apology, should not have posted in a hurry.

Comment: Apologize. Still in hurry :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could just sort in one direction, then check if required direction is the opposite. If yes, then reverse the existing array.

```
public static void numbers(int[] array, char direction){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++){

            if(array[j] < array[j + 1]){
                int tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    if(direction=='>'){
            var reverseArray=array.clone();
            Collections.reverse(Array.asList(reverseArray));
    }

    // Now you have your ascending order in 'array' and descending order in 'reverseArray'.
}
```